# Clip raster by mask layer attempt gives ERROR 1: netCDF chunk fetch failed

Tags: clip, extract-by-mask

When trying to clip raster by Mask layer I get the following error:
My input layer is a TIFF file, the mask layer a shapefile.

```
ERROR 1: netcdf error #-62 : NetCDF: One or more variable sizes violate format constraints . 
at (D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.7.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::SetDefineMode,3005) 

ERROR 1: netCDF chunk fetch failed: #-39 (NetCDF: Operation not allowed in define mode) 
ERROR 1: C:/Users/valerie/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_XIiQRD/30290ab551af4cd3b3307b4666fbae7b/OUTPUT.nc, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: netCDF chunk fetch failed: #-39 (NetCDF: Operation not allowed in define mode)
ERROR 1: netcdf error #-39 : NetCDF: Operation not allowed in define mode . 
at (D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.7.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,6758) 

ERROR 1: netcdf error #-39 : NetCDF: Operation not allowed in define mode . 
at (D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.7.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,6763)
ERROR 1: netcdf error #-62 : NetCDF: One or more variable sizes violate format constraints . 
at (D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.7.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::Close,2964)
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 4.60 seconds

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/valerie/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_XIiQRD/30290ab551af4cd3b3307b4666fbae7b/OUTPUT.nc
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Default output raster layer extension (in Settings->Options->Processing->General) to a value other than "nc" e.g. to the value "tif" which is the default for such option.